# Проблема с плавным отображение в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Программа должна крутить куб на который наложена текстура.

***Но есть проблема:*** первые 17 секунд такое чувство, что программа глючит - куб вращается и камера двигается рывками, а после 17 секунд все работает плавно. 
Я понял, что если в "Game loop" закомментировать вывод переменных, то лаги пропадают:

```
std::cout << "-------------------------" << std::endl;
std::cout << "lastFrame - " << lastFrame << std::endl;
std::cout << "currentFrame - " << currentFrame << std::endl;
std::cout << "deltaTime - " << deltaTime << std::endl;
```

Проблема, как я понял, в deltatime. Как можно это исправить, чтоб и в консоль выводились данные и не "лагало" окно отображение?

***Мой код:***

*main.cpp*

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <soil.h>

#include "shader.h"
#include "Camera.h"

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;


// Properties
GLuint screenWidth = 800, screenHeight = 600;

// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void Do_Movement();

// Camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
bool keys[1024];
GLfloat lastX = 400, lastY = 300;
bool firstMouse = true;

GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;



// The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);


    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Barebuh", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);
    // GLFW Options
    //glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Build and compile our shader program
    Shader ourShader(
        "D:\\Programming\\cpp\\UDEMY\\OpenGLCourseApp\\Shaders\\vert\\shader.vert",
        "D:\\Programming\\cpp\\UDEMY\\OpenGLCourseApp\\Shaders\\frag\\shader.frag"
    );

    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    // World space positions of our cubes
    glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = {
        glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
    };


    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Position attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        // TexCoord attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO


    // Load and create a texture 
    GLuint texture1;
    GLuint texture2;
    // ====================
    // Texture 1
    // ====================
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); // All upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on our texture object
    // Set our texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // Set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set texture filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Load, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("../img/box.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind texture when done, so we won't accidentily mess up our texture.



    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
        std::cout << "-------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "lastFrame - " << lastFrame << std::endl;
        std::cout << "currentFrame - " << currentFrame << std::endl;
        std::cout << "deltaTime - " << deltaTime << std::endl;


        // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
        glfwPollEvents();
        Do_Movement();

        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "blur"), 0.2);
        // Bind Textures using texture units
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture1"), 0);

        // Activate shader
        ourShader.Use();


        // Create transformations
        glm::mat4 view;
        // Create camera transformation
        view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection");
        // Pass the matrices to the shader
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        // Note: currently we set the projection matrix each frame, but since the projection matrix rarely changes it's often best practice to set it outside the main loop only once.
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        // Calculate the model matrix for each object and pass it to shader before drawing
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[0]);
            model = glm::rotate(model, (GLfloat)glfwGetTime() * glm::radians(50.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        glBindVertexArray(0);



        glClearDepth(1.0);
        // Swap the screen buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


// Moves/alters the camera positions based on user input
void Do_Movement()
{
    // Camera controls
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_W])
        camera.processKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_S])
        camera.processKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_A])
        camera.processKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (keys[GLFW_KEY_D])
        camera.processKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    //cout << key << endl;
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    if (key >= 0 && key < 1024)
    {
        if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
            keys[key] = true;
        else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
            keys[key] = false;
    }
}

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    GLfloat xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    GLfloat yoffset = lastY - ypos;  // Reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to left

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}


void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}
```

*shader.h*

https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?type=header&code=shader

*camera.h*

https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?type=header&code=camera

*shader.vert:*

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

*shader.frag:*

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;

void main()
{
    color = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord);
}
```

Comment: да лагать может из-за того что текст долго выводиться в консоль. ещё glgetuniformlocation лучше делать один раз для класса например и потом просто использовать эти переменные.

Comment: можно переменные поместить в `std::atomic<GLfloat>`, а вывод в другой thread